# How to create back button in table view in iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk

Hi

I want to create back button and place in table view page.

That is I need when I press button it will goes next page of tableview page from one UIView subclass to table view control class.

Here i need to create navigation controller with back button in iPhone.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Should you use the back button to go back to previous page?

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Title of back view";
```

This will do.

Comment: Go to this tutorial link http://cocoadevblog.com/uinavigationcontroller-customization-tutorial.

Comment: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/ one more link.